# Excel VBA - receiving Compile Error: Expected: #

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to set the column width for one column across most of sheets in my workbook.

The code looks like this:

```
Sub width()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name = "NAD SHEET" Or ws.Name = "BoM" Or ws.Name = "BoQ" Or ws.Name = "Sign Off Sheet" 
Or ws.Name = "PIANOI" Then
'do nothing
Else
ws.Range("M").ColumnWidth = 12.67
End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

I am getting an error:

[image]

Compile error: Expected: #

I tried also

```
With
ws.Range("M").ColumnWidth = 12.67
End With
```

as well as

```
ws.Range("M1:M").ColumnWidth = 12.67
```

still the same.

I don't know what is going on really here.

Comment: Use `Range("M:M")`

Comment: It was the same, I tried it too

Comment: Have you tried restarting Excel?

Comment: As it is a compile error you should have a red line in your code ... I suppose it is in a different sub. Or: what happens if you set the width to 12?

Comment: Try putting your entire `If` statement on one line first (you put an `Or` on a new line) and then see if it compiles.

Comment: You might want to put some brackets around the clauses in your `IF` statement too

Comment: @NickSlash  Why?

Comment: And change the name of the routine to something else, like `setWidth()`

Comment: @FunThomas, looks like VBA doesn't need it. In other languages I find it helps to remove uncertainty if you've got statements with lots of logical comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 things in your code that are incorrect.

First, the if statement need to be in 1 line(like @braX said). If you really want it be 2 lines, put a " _" at the end of first line.

Second, like @Rory said, use Range("M:M")

After testing the code, it's running ok on my computer:

```
 Sub width()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name = "NAD SHEET" Or ws.Name = "BoM" Or ws.Name = "BoQ" Or ws.Name = "Sign Off Sheet" _
            Or ws.Name = "PIANOI" Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                ws.Range("M:M").ColumnWidth = 12.67
            End If
        Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, I get the same error as the OP unless the routine is renamed - presumably due to a conflict with the native `Width` routine.